# Transpile CKEditor to ES5 using Webpack/Laravel mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, ckeditor

CKEditor does not work in iOS 10 (Safari).

I have found a guide that describes how to transpile it to ES5 which should get it working. I try to make it work with Laravel. The guide is here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#option-building-to-es5-target

I try to make it work using Laravel Mix, but it is not my strongest skill, though I have tried. From Laravels doc, the problem may be solved with something like:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        module: {
                rules: [
                {
                     test: /ckeditor5-[^\/\\]+[\/\\].*\.js$/,
                     use: [
                             {
                                 loader: 'babel-loader',
                                 options: {
                                   presets: [ require( '@babel/preset-env' ) ]
                                 }
                             }
                          ]
                },
               ]
            }
      }
});
```

but I cannot get it to work.
I have also considered making a copy of webpack.config.js like explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#custom-webpack-configuration

But again I get in doubt when I try to solve the issue (it's most related to the syntax). Have anyone tried to get CKEditor to work in Safari iOS 10 using Laravel?

In advance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i know you asked for this long ago, but i stumbled into the same problem today.

i solved following the docs with a little trick, in your webpack.mix.js

```
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin' );
const CKEStyles = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils').styles;
const CKERegex = {
    svg: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
    css: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/,
};


Mix.listen('configReady', webpackConfig => {
const rules = webpackConfig.module.rules;
const targetSVG = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;
const targetFont = /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/;
const targetCSS = /\.css$/;

// exclude CKE regex from mix's default rules
for (let rule of rules) {
    if (rule.test.toString() === targetSVG.toString()) {
        rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
    }
    else if (rule.test.toString() === targetFont.toString()) {
        rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
    }
    else if (rule.test.toString() === targetCSS.toString()) {
        rule.exclude = CKERegex.css;
    }
}
});
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
        language: 'it'
      })
   ],
   module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /ckeditor5-[^\/\\]+[\/\\].+\.js$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: Config.babel()
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: CKERegex.svg,
            use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: CKERegex.css,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: {
                        singleton: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: CKEStyles.getPostCssConfig({
                        themeImporter: {
                            themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                        },
                        minify: true
                    })
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
});
```

be sure to follow the documentation for installing the correct packages!